# Is it possible to change VS Code's error message length?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there was a possibility to see the whole error message in VS Code.

What I mean is for example this one:

```
 Type '{ queryParamMap: string | boolean | ParamMap | SomeArray[]; showSpinner: string | boolean | ParamMap | SomeArray[]; ... 9 more ...; someFilter: string | ... 2 more ... | SomeArray[]; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

I'd like to see / know what are those which were hidden by ... 9 more ... and ... 2 more ... .

Please not that this given in an Angular application.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the output of tsc

Comment: Thanks for the comment @tscpp, however as this is an Angular application I can't seem to find anything in the Output / tsc tab and in the Problems pane it's giving me the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it's not editor specific but you can achieve this by setting `"noErrorTruncation": true,` in your tsconfing.json file.